# Show message errors after to petition AJAX Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I'm developing an application with laravel 5, and sent the information by AJAX, but if I want to display error messages generated by FormRequest ? because in the browser console in Network -> preview can see that error message

My FormRequest CreateRequest

```
<?php

 namespace Cinema\Http\Requests;

 use Cinema\Http\Requests\Request;

   class CreateRequest extends Request
   {

     public function authorize()
     {
       return true;
      }


      public function rules()
     {
       return [
          'genre' => 'required',
       ];
     }
 }
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

 namespace Cinema\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Cinema\Http\Requests;
 use Cinema\Http\Requests\CreateRequest;
 use Cinema\Http\Controllers\Controller;

 class GenreController extends Controller
 {

public function store(CreateRequest $request)
{

    if ($request->ajax())
        {
        return response()->json([
            'petition' => $request->all()
            ],200);
        }
}
}
```

My petition AJAX:

```
$("#registro").click(function(){
var data = $("#genre").val();
var route = "http://localhost:8000/genero";
var token = document.getElementById('token').value

$.ajax({
url: route,
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {data : data},

});


});
```

And i can see the message error in the console:
[image]

But how can display? , Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Just for test purpose - have an empty div in your view with an id of result:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Try this bit of code on ajax .fail:

```
    .fail(function(data) {

            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            var displayErrors = '<ul>';

            $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                displayErrors += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
            });

            displayErrors += '</ul>';
            $('#result').html(displayErrors);

        });
```

Like I said in the beginning - You can change the **#result** div to where you want the errors to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller..

```
<?php

 namespace Cinema\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Cinema\Http\Requests;
 use Cinema\Http\Requests\CreateRequest;
 use Cinema\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class GenreController extends Controller
{

    public function store(CreateRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
           return response()->json([
             'petition' => $request->all(),
             'success' => true   // Add this line as a success flag
           ],200);
        }
    }
}
```

And your ajax..

```
$("#registro").click(function(){
    var data = $("#genre").val();
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/genero";
    var token = document.getElementById('token').value

    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {data : data},
        success: function(data){
            if(typeof data.success === "undefined"){
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                var displayErrors = '<ul>';

                $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                    displayErrors += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
                });

                displayErrors += '</ul>';
                $('#result').html(displayErrors);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And like the previous answer you can add a div element where you want to show your validation errors.

```
<div id="result"></div>
```